# Disable dot as word separator in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a problem with dot char in creating my own language support in vs code.

In supporting word completion i have words such as "aaa.bbb" and then when i type "aaa" i see all examples with "aaa.[xxx]", but then when i type dot "aaa." completion clears and when i start typing "b" vs code tries to find all words with "b" instead of "aaa.b".
 Tried to disable dot in vs code settings in separators and in triggering chars, but it doesn't work.

about functions to support - i just copy-pasted .php support and modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found solution for this.
Just needed to add dot to regex in CompletionItemProvider.

[image]